# Java AES decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am encrypting some data and then sending it over the network and finally decrypting that data on an Android device using the class below. The encryption happens on the java server and then the decryption happens on the phone. I am getting this error though when I decrypt the data on the phone, “javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted”. I don't get this error when I run my unit tests on the computer. Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class Encryption {
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = 
    new byte[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' };

public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    return encryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    return key;
}

private static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Chances are your encrypted data is fragmented on the way to your phone, and you're attempting to decrypt before you have the entire block. Ensure you do this.

Comment: Padding errors will happen 255 out of 256 times when the (end of the) data is corrupted, when the keys are different, when partial data is send. For short plain text it could even be that the wrong IV was used but that's only for those modes that use one. Unrelated, you should never call `new String(byte[])` or `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding, especially between two different platforms.

Comment: @super_ well, actually if you are decrypting a partial block you should get an error on the input size, not a `BadPaddingException`. But if the data transfer is borked, this could lead to a `BadPaddingException`

Comment: Could you try and decrypt using `AES/ECB/NoPadding` and post the result using some sample text? Have you tried the methods on the same platform? Which `BASE64Decoder` are you using?

Comment: You cannot use sun.misc.BASE64Decoder on the Android platform. Are you *sure* you are posting everything here?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the two platforms are using different default values for the mode and/or padding. If you specify just the cipher, the underlying implementation will select a mode and padding for you.

Try specifying the exact cipher/mode/padding you want on both ends:

Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

This is just an example. Use the mode and padding that you want.

Comment: And don't use AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for text as it leaks information about the data. AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding should be the default on both sides though.